# Let us (continue to) close old, off-topic questions about web hosting control panels

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, old-questions, cleanup

I'm not going to rehash all the [drama](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8054/126632) of the last few days surrounding our [former moderator](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8071/126632) HopelessN00b's mass closing of old, off-topic questions about web hosting control panels, but something important was put on hold during that mess and needs to be revisited:

There is, and has been for years, a [broad community consensus that most such questions should be closed (or migrated) and that old questions should be sought out and closed as well](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055/126632).

Unfortunately I do not have the time to go through and clean all of these up myself, and the person who did is no longer going to be doing so.

Nevertheless I think that we should continue to identify and close these questions, if possible, and I would like to ask you all to help.

If you have extra close votes near the end of a (UTC) day, search for such questions and vote to close them, based on the consensus criteria:

- **End user questions should be closed**; these are off-topic *anyway*, so close them using the *"Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment."* off-topic reason.
- **Admin questions should be closed with a custom close reason** referring the user to the web hosting control panel vendor's support channels. These questions can also be flagged for migration to Webmasters if they aren't too old to migrate, and [they are "about a website."](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343/17007)
- **Questions where the web hosting control panel is incidental should remain open** if they are otherwise on topic. These are questions where the answer would be exactly the same whether the web hosting control panel was present or not, and edited to remove extraneous references to the web hosting control panel. If you aren't sure, skip it. If such a question needs to be closed for a different reason, that reason should not mention the web hosting control panel.

I would also be very happy to see our other moderators help with this, and I'll also do so when I have time (which unfortunately won't be that much).

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  It's too bad that we can't kill old, off-topic web hosting panel questions with our brains. </Firefly>

Comment: There are [a lot](http://serverfault.com/search?q=cpanel+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+score%3A-0) that are easily found and are [quite](http://serverfault.com/questions/242540/varnish-cache-on-apache2-cpanel) [bad](http://serverfault.com/questions/182947/how-to-share-files-between-cpanel-accounts). And could be closed for a number of reasons. However if we organize this as a community effort don't we risk bloating our close queue even further? I don't actually have access to that queue yet (useless newcomer that I am) but it always seems to hang just shy of a hundred in the queue.

Comment: @Reaces, see http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6663 and add your vote there for increasing the number of close votes allowed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : It could also be phrased as don’t let Server Fault becoming a Super User duplicate.

Comment: -1 for not formulating this in the form of a question

Comment: @Yuck [Meta works differently from the main site.](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Yuck : Doing this only stand as you are against this change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're gonna do this, let's do it right:

1. **[Define a custom off-topic reason.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184637/what-do-site-moderators-need-to-do-to-support-the-new-custom-question-close-reas/185097#185097)** Doesn't have to be a permanent addition, but for the purpose of this cleanup swapping one in means less tedious clicking for the folks closing. More importantly, it means we're not notifying hundreds of people while conducting this campaign: kinda rude to drag folks back only to tell them something they wrote [days|months|years] ago is now disallowed.

   Make something *specific and descriptive* and link to your meta discussion from it; ideally, this should describe why these questions are being closed well enough that anyone reading won't be confused. This is something you & the rest of the mods can do at any time.
2. **[Increase the number of close votes available.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6663/can-we-increase-the-number-of-close-votes-per-day)** That's probably over-due anyway; ping me once you have #1 squared away & I'll take care of this.
3. **Keep an eye on [the close review queue](https://serverfault.com/review/close).** Hopefully folks are balancing their time between working through the backlog and reviewing questions others have found, but if it starts to pile up then encourage others to pitch in before going back to the cleanup. Also, make sure no one's getting fatigued; if anyone appears to be reviewing blindly, encourage them to take a break - yes, this needs to be done, but it doesn't need to be a death-march.

Comment: Before I go write another meta post to define this custom off-topic reason, can we get the fifth slot for it? As far as I know all four of our existing close reasons are well-used and it may be a problem to remove any of them, even temporarily. (And I expect this cleanup to take 6 to 8 weeks...)

Comment: A [custom off-topic reason](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8096/we-need-a-custom-close-reason-for-web-hosting-control-panels) has been defined and comments on it are welcome.

Comment: Also, y'all, I've had a couple of people say, "Why are you commenting on my five year old post?" so you might want to be prepared to answer something like, "We're doing a big web panel cleanup and your question was in the review queue/came up in search/whatever.  No offense meant;  your question was probably on topic in [year] when you asked it," or whatever.  The people I've spoken to have been very nice and understanding about it.

Comment: This is the #1 reason why I want this to be a baked-in OT reason, @KatherineVillyard. Unless you're willing to sit down & discuss the merits of these questions, notifying folks via comments is just plain rude; if they're clearly off-topic it's best to close quietly and move on. I should add that to this answer...

Comment: You got a 5th slot, @MichaelHampton - make it happen!

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. I'm waiting for a little more feedback on the close reason first, though.

Comment: Take your time; you & the rest of the team can handle this from here.

Comment: It *is* clearly something we've discussed on meta, and one person volunteered that he knew it was no longer on topic.  But yes, a baked-in reason would be much nicer.  I'm perfectly willing to link to the meta discussion, and like I said, no offense is meant.  The questions were on topic when asked.

Comment: I notice that the number of close votes available has been increased, but I am still only allowed to review 20 questions per day in the close votes queue. Is that intentional?

Comment: @kasperd the allotted amount of reviews is elastic, if there are more than 1k reviews you have 40 reviews per day, less than that only 20.

Comment: @Braiam There are never that many reviews in the queue. I haven't even seen it reach 100.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a little confused as to why we need to spend time retroactively closing these questions.  I agree that they are now OT in most cases (not all- but certainly most), and new questions should be closed.  What do we get from looking fir them specifically?

Comment: Discouraging users who find these questions via Internet searches from asking more of them.

Comment: I'm also much more a proponent of just closing the questions as they pop up on the front page / get used as a reason for creating new OT questions in stead of mass closing. I don't think we're helping our community feel like their input matters by asking them to spend time cleaning up old stuff just on the off chance that they'll be used as an argument. If someone brings it up on meta that they thought it was OT because they found an old question, then clearly they're interested and curious, two good qualities for SF.

Comment: It certainly is interesting that we have a group of users with the idea that there is such a huge volume of new cpanel questions that the flood cannot be handled.  So much so that the number of new questions would come close to or exceed the effort required to close all the old ones.

Comment: In some way I feel that cPanel is our Moby Dick...

Comment: Discouraging users from *anything* should not be on-topic in a professional sysadmin exchange. (But I have upvoted on the closing, just to make that clear)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Such questions could be closed (as crap) or migrated to Unix / SU. There was a "historical" tag, or they could have been locked as well.

Answer (score -14):

Simply closing and later deleting questions in a mass, instead of migrating them, is simply barbarism. Especially doing it retroactively.

Why a migration path to webapps SE doesn't exist?

**Extension #1:** @EEAA noted vast majority of such questions are crap. But

1. not all of them
2. then close & destroy the questions because they are crap, and not because they would be offtopic!

**Extension #2:** @mesagoleh noted, questions older as 60 days can't be migrated. Well, it is because you are now applying a newly invented rule retroactively! What are you doing now, is brainless destruction!

Comment: [Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/260672). And in the title above, @MichaelHampton ♦ explicitly 'invite' us to close **old, off-topic question**

Comment: @masegaloeh In case of them it would be anyways a retroactive rule. They should soon remain.

Comment: Would you like to edit your post and clarify what do you mean by *retroactive rule*? :)

Comment: @masegaloeh What you don't understand?

Comment: The vast majority of these questions are crap. [We don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446). Which [you've been reminded of quite recently](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8041/suggestion-helping-amateurs-to-get-their-way-to-su-unix-se/8042#comment17307_8042).

Comment: @EEAA What is crap, you should close because it is crap, and not because offtopic!

Comment: If it takes "brainless destruction" to help convince people that these control panels are an abomination, then I'm all for it. Honestly, though, these questions are adding no value to the site. Additionally, this is not the first time the community has clarified its understanding of topicality and then retroactively closed a bunch of questions. Same thing happened with shopping/product recommendation questions. And we're *still* cleaning up old questions from that one.

Comment: @EEAA Not in all case! What is abonimation, that absolute beginners are coming here and show their hilarious php CPanel warnings! _They_ had to be migrated or eliminated, and not on the ground of offtopic, but on the ground of "unclear", "not professional" or "very low quality"! What is also a real abonimation, is that the site invents a rule, and destroys a considerable part of its content retroactively!

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion.