# Can we increase review queue limits?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, reviewing, review-audits

[Since the number of close votes has been increased](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6663/can-we-increase-the-number-of-close-votes-per-day), Can we view more questions in the review queue? It currently still shows only 20 or so.

Comment: Take my upboats. The queue's growing fairly rapidly and outpaces people doing reviews.

Comment: Once Upon a Time, the 10K tools (which I no longer see, as I have mod-tools) had a listing of questions-with-close-votes on them. Is that tool still there, or did it go away when the review-queues came in?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Ah, good point. I do see that one...it'll help for sure.

Comment: If the close queue is under 100 I am not at all concerned.

Comment: You *can* still see the 10K tools, @sysadmin1138 - http://serverfault.com/tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, note that the limit automatically increases if the backlog gets *really* big. It's more or less permanently 40/day on Stack Overflow simply because thousands get *added* every day.

But 20 reviews per day, *every day*, is a lot of reviews. Very few people have that kind of stamina.

Yes, it's tempting to sit down and do 40, 50, 500/day when you're starting out. That gets really old really fast. Moderators have unlimited reviews, and yet the reviewing-est moderator I'm aware of on any site still usually did well under < 100 per day. If you're in this for the long haul, you don't want to burn out on it.

That's not even getting into issues of fatigue; even at 20, it's not uncommon to see folks getting a bit sloppy toward the end, especially if they're also active in other review queues.

If it needs to be increased for the purpose of finishing the current cleanup, we can do that, but hopefully that isn't necessary. Encourage more people to review; many hands make light work.

FWIW, y'all are keeping up so far:

[image: close tasks, reviews, and backlog, last 4 weeks]

Close review is looking healthier now than it has in a while. Keep it up...

Comment: Yeah, it's depressing in large doses.  You have to stop from time to time or you go blind.

Comment: I hear you, Shog, but the highest-voted answer in the request for more close votes (linked above) predicted that given an increase in close votes without a concomitant increase in review queue limits, we'd see a jump in the size of the review queues.  So far, that seems to be exactly what's happened.

Comment: That's [not at all clear](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ED961.png) just yet, @MadHatter - it could easily happen if too many people drop out of reviewing, but right now you seem to be doing a good job of keeping on top of it.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Agreed, occasionally one has to stop and wonder what the average quality of questions on this site is. If only there was another queue where one could go look on good questions for a while to get some encouragement.

Comment: It's partly the phenomenon I see in my wrists group--sometimes someone will want to send the same story through multiple times, until the group runs out of things to say about it, but after two times through I can't remember whether something happened in version two or version three any more--and partly, "Oh yawn, oh stretch, let's crush some hopes and blight some dreams!", :( and partly yeah,  "Wow, some of these questions are really bad!"  In the other hand, the queue being large offends my sensibilities.  And yeah, it would be nice to go read a good question queue, heh.

Comment: ("Blight hopes and crush dreams" is kind of an inside critique group joke, but it feels applicable.)

Comment: I'm fond of [the right column in 10k stats](http://serverfault.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last30days) @katherine

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to close something in the queue, you can click through to the Question and close it there.  I know this isn't a good answer, since it's a pain, but it's what I plan on doing when I get to 12345 reviews.

I kinda - but not too much - object to people getting more reviews, they should have to get up to 10,000+ the old-fashioned, 20-at-a-time way.